# add multiple panels into a form

Tags: c#, winforms

hi I'm trying to create a list that contains my customised Panel called MyPanel, and add the panels in the list to my from. however it seems like when Form1 load, the form is actually showing 1 panel instead of 10 panels in total. here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<MyPanel> tenPanels = new List<MyPanel>(); 
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                MyPanel mp = new MyPanel();
                tenPanels.Add(mp);
                mp.Name = "digitPanel" + i;
                mp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10+i, 32);
                mp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(147, 173);
                this.Controls.Add(mp);
            }
            foreach(Panel p in tenPanels)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(p);
            }
        }
```

Form1_Load is visual studio automatically generated event

Comment: Shouldn't `10+i` be something more like `10 + (i * 147)` ?

Comment: You're adding each panel twice, there's no need for the final `foreach`

Comment: If you put ten panels right on top of each other, you'll only see the top-most panel. It seems likely that if you fix the code according to commenter Dan-o's suggestion, you'll see all your panels. Of course, you should also fix the redundant loop to call `Add()`; it's not harming anything per se, but it's also not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least three problems.

1, You are trying to add each new MyPanel twice, once in the main loop and then again in another loop afterwards. I recommend you remove the second loop entirely.

2, The calculated position of each new panel is only 1 pixel to the right of the last one, which means they are going to overlap and hide each other. So update the Point to something sensible.

3, Each time you are adding a new panel the window will perform layout calculations. You could reduce this by asking the control to wait until the last one is added before updating its layout. This will give better performance.

```
this.BeginUpdate();

// your code

this.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: thanks! I know I'm adding the panels twice cause I'm trying to add those panels to from1 in different ways; haven't noticed that I only make the new panel 1 pixel to the right of the last one, it clearly overlap with the previous one; by the way should I place the BeginUpdate() EndUpdate() around my "for" loop?

Comment: this.SuspendLayout();
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                MyPanel mp = new MyPanel();
                tenPanels.Add(mp);
                mp.Name = "digitPanel" + i;
                mp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10+i*10, 32);
                mp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(147, 173);
                this.Controls.Add(mp);
            }
            this.ResumeLayout();